Does Azure firewall drop packets with SYN+ECE_CWR flags set
There are tcp retransmissions after SYN+ECE+CWR transmission. I want to know whether you have experienced a behavior where azure firewall silently dropping packets like this intermittently.
Unable to reproduce this again. Therefore, can someone post how to reproduce this.
